# General question about iOS app structure and mixing Obj-C, standard C, C++ etc

Tags: ios

An iOS app would contain Objective-C / Cocoa, traditional C and possibly C++.
Is it a good practice to keep these physically separated (in different source files)?
I know an .mm file is actually all of these at once but I'm looking for opinions as to how to structure these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible answers is make project which contain main program and several static(I don't know about dynamic libs support) libraries (different parts of application) to combine them into one application later

Comment: I'm actually not thinking about having multiple standalone components; this is for a single monolithic app.  I'm wondering if splitting the .c, .m, etc. would be something you'd recommend for clarity.  Or perhaps it's not really a big deal :)

Comment: yes, for clarity only at this point. and also for better code testing (unit tests and complex).